# How to build lambda to compare both list?

Tags: c#, list, lambda, compare

Now for example I have two list as below:

```
List<ABC> testingList_1 = new List<ABC>;
List<ABC> testingList_2 = new List<ABC>;
```

`ABC` contain a type `List<ZZZ>, ABC_ID`
`List<ZZZ>` contain a type `List<YYY>, ZZZ_ID`
`List<YYY>` contain `YYY_ID, Name`

Now I'm trying to compare between `Name` of `YYY` in `testingList_1` and `Name` of `YYY` in `testingList_2`. May I know how to construct such lambda?

Answer (score 0):

Well, that depends on what kind of comparison you are doing. For example, if you wanted to see if any "YYY" names in testingList1 were in testingList2, you would use a `SelectMany` with a `Any` condition:

```
return testingList1.SelectMany(x => x.zList).Any(y => testingList2.SelectMany(z => z.Zlist).Contains(y.Name));
```

Other comparisons would be similar, they all take advantage of the `SelectMany` function, which allows you to apply a selector that returns an `IEnumerable` and effectively "flatten" or combine all the results into one large `IEnumerable`.

Documentation for SelectMany: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Please let me know if I can clarify anything!